# Loading different view without using segue based on NSUserDefaults value

Tags: ios

I have the following in my initial view controller. I do a check to see if the URL is set; if it is I segue to that view.

There is an animation when this happens. I would like to avoid doing the segue and directly load the view without any animation. (I want it to look like it was their first view). Is there a way to do this? Do I need to modify app delegate? What is the best practice?

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* url = [defaults objectForKey:@"storeUrl"];

    if (url != nil)
    {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"continueToStore" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what controller actually holds your view. If you have navigation controller you can do:

```
// remove topmost controller so user won't get back here
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

// instantiate your controller (set identifier in storyboard's Identity section)
StoreWebViewController *storeController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoreWebViewController"];

// push new controller on top of a stack
[self.navigationController pushViewController:storeController animated:NO];
```

Put this code instead of your segue (see code below)

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // rest of code omitted
    ...

    if (url != nil)
    {
        // code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should this code be? In the AppDelegate or the main view that loads?

Comment: @ChrisMuench please, see updated code in my post. thanks

Comment: I am getting error ] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle. I have 2 storyboards Main_iPhone and Main_iPad. I really don't want to have code to decide which one to use. Is there an easier way?

Comment: I tried to use self.storyboard, but got a different error: 2014-03-09 19:23:42.775 PHP POS[18570:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0xa4807b0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'StoreWebViewController'. There is StoreWebViewController in the storyboard. Do I have to set an ID somehow?

Comment: I set Storyboard ID in the storyboard file and it worked. I will edit your answer with my final code.

Comment: @ChrisMuench yeap, this is better solution. Thanks for editing!

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
[yourNavigationController pushViewController:new_view_controller animated:NO];
```

and this should be done not in `- (void) viewDidAppear` of course.